# Creating a stacked area distribution percentile graph in Google Cloud Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, system-monitoring

I've created a log based metric using logs stored in Google Cloud Logs based on HTTP response duration.  I'd like to a graph which shows stacked area for 50th, 95th, and 99th percentile.

I've read the Google Cloud Monitoring docs on various charts and while I can get any single metric to display as a percentile; I can't seem to have all three percentiles render stacked at the same time.

What *is* possible is adding the 3 percentiles to a chart as 3 separate metrics with different alignment which seems to work well for regular line charts but if I change the chart type to stacked area then each percentile shades its area independentally of the other percentile lines.

I can also get all three lines to show up if I select a "Heatmap" chart with `sum` or `delta` alignment and click 'hide heatmap' button on the chart in Metrics explorer.

This is a very common way to visualize distribution percentiles so I think it should be possible (may by editing the query direction to include multiple percentiles) so any help is appreciated.

**Metric Details:**

Type: Distribution

Filter: `logName = "projects/lv-server-1/logs/tail-logs" AND jsonPayload.httpRequest:*`

Units: s

Field name: jsonPayload.duration

Labels:

- "status, INTEGER, jsonPayload.status"
- 'content_type, STRING,jsonPayload.resp_headers."Content-Type"'

Histogram Buckets:

- Type: Exponential
- Number of Buckets: 64
- Exponetnial growth Factor: 2.0
- Linear scale: .00005

Comment: In order to make the reproduction of the scenario, please could you share exactly same log based metrics, and which is the limit for a http response duration time. We have to take into account that the aligned data point is valid only for gauge and delta metrics when they have a distribution data type, as seen in [Align data's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/selecting-aggregating-metrics#alignment).

Comment: Hi @Pedro, I updated the question with more details. I included the histogram buckets since that exactly gives the limit of recorded HTTP response duration times.

Comment: Please could you share as well the build filters? This [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67742984/gcp-alert-filters-criteria-for-multiple-resources) might be helpful.

Comment: I added the metric filters as well. The similar post seems to be related to metrics and alerting but I think my problem is more on how to create charts for my metrics. Though perhaps there's some way to use `||` in the query editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what seems to be the answer on stackoverflow after reading the Monitoring Query Language docs.

[`union_group_by`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#union_group_by-tabop) allows you to chart multiple time series at once which would allow stacked area graph to work correctly. I searched for examples of usage and came across this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68115446/15947423) which had been posted recently.

Essentially, you create a table of percentiles from your latency data and then pass it to `union_group_by`:

> ```
> fetch global::logging.googleapis.com/user/my_metrics.response_time |
> {
>     percentile_from 50 | add [p: "50th percentile"]
>     ;
>     percentile_from 90 | add [p: "90th percentile"]
>     ;
>     percentile_from 95 | add [p: "95th percentile"]
> } |
> union_group_by [p]
> ```

The resulting graph is stacked correctly but uses a different interpolation than when using the basic editor's percentile aligner. The values seem roughly correct though.